# Unable to connect printer on Ubuntu 12.04 which is shared on windows 7 pc

Tags: networking, printing

I have a HP Laserjet m1005 printer which is connected to a Windows 7 pc

I also have an Ubuntu 12.04 PC both are connected through LAN cable in a network.

I want to share the printer with the Ubuntu 12.04 PC

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set up printer sharing with a Windows 7 machine in Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/641/how-do-i-set-up-printer-sharing-with-a-windows-7-machine-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Open Ubuntu System Settings window and click the Printers icon. Click the Add button to add a new printer.

[image]

Expand the Network Printer section, select Windows Printer via SAMBA, and click the Browse button. You’ll be able to browse available network printers connected to different computers on the network. Add the printer to your PC, configure its drivers, and it will appear as an available printer when printing from Linux applications.

[image]

In this [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/191323/how-to-share-printers-between-windows-mac-and-linux-pcs-on-a-network/) you can find the solutions for other Operating Systems too.